# VBA: How to color a duplicate row?

Tags: vba, excel, row

im new to vba and i need help to color the duplicate row instead of only the cell that this do, anyone that can help me out here.

```
Sub FindDuplicate()

Dim cel As Variant
Dim myrng As Range
Dim clr As Long

Set myrng = Range("S2:S" & Range("S65536").End(xlUp).row)
myrng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
clr = 3

For Each cel In myrng
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myrng, cel) > 1 Then
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("S2:S" & cel.row), cel) = 1 Then
            cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        Else
            cel.Interior.ColorIndex = myrng.Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(cel.Value, myrng, False), 1).Interior.ColorIndex
        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, change

```
cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
```

to

```
Rows(cel.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with jeanno's answer, thanks.

I added:

```
Rows(cel.row).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        Else
            Rows(cel.row).Interior.ColorIndex = myrng.Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(cel.Value, myrng, False), 1).Interior.ColorIndex
```